# Windows azure - the specified table not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to get the daa from windows azure storage but I'm getting table not found. I've already saw the others answers but nothing works...

I did try this:

```
 private void popula()
        {
            var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Conn"));
            account.CreateCloudTableClient().CreateTableIfNotExist("fiscal");
            var context = new CRUDManifestacoesEntities(account.TableEndpoint.ToString(), account.Credentials);

            Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)ViewState["filtro"];
            var teste = ViewState["x"].ToString();
            if (ht == null)
                GridView1.DataSource = context.SelectConc(teste);
            else
                GridView1.DataSource = context.SelectConc(ht);
}



  public List<ManifestacaoGrid> SelectConc(string conc)
      {
          conc = Crypto.DecryptString(conc);
          IQueryable<ManifestacaoEntity> results = null;
          if (!conc.Equals("dfg"))
              results = from c in ManifestacaoEntities where c.concessionaria == conc select c;
          else
              results = from c in ManifestacaoEntities select c;

          var query = results.AsTableServiceQuery<ManifestacaoEntity>();
          var queryResults = query.Execute();

          List<ManifestacaoGrid> al = new List<ManifestacaoGrid>();

          foreach (ManifestacaoEntity mf in queryResults)
          {

                  .......
               }
```

I'm getting this error:

> `TableNotFound`The table specified does not exist.
>   RequestId:285f6ef7-b1ce-4c21-9406-3e9f6a58755b
>   Time:2014-01-15T14:30:55.7989535Z

**EDIT**: I did print '_account' to see if the credentials are correct:
var credencial = "Connection string with sensitive data: " + account.ToString(true);
and the AccountName and AccountKey are correct ...but how can I know if the requested table is correct?
The secundary key is needed in storage account?

Comment: With the code you have shared, it would be difficult to find the cause of the error. I would recommend executing this code with Fiddler running so that you can see in the request to storage which table is being called. HTH.

Comment: I did execute the code with Fiddler but I don't see the which table is being called. I seeGET http://127.0.0.1:81/grid.aspx?x=EPt7ub3kgyfYf6xEdC0zjg== HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:81
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:81/login.aspx
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=tjqsuvlckbixr5znsst0p35i
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().CreateTableIfNotExist("theNameOfMyTable"); How Know I the name of my table?

Comment: There must be somewhere in your code where you're defining the name of the table. I would look into either `CRUDManifestacoesEntities` or `ManifestacaoEntity` class.

Comment: The method that execute the query is selectConc in CRUDManifestacoesEntities. Pls, see in my question the code from selectConc. There is no table name in this method.

Comment: I did open my qindows azure storage with "Azure Storage Explorer" and theres a table named "fiscal"....

Answer (score 0):

I did found the problem. I write

```
public IQueryable<UserEntity> UserEntities
  {
      get
      {
          return this.CreateQuery<UserEntity>("tableName");
      }
  }
```

Instead of:

```
   public IQueryable<UserEntity> UserEntities
      {
          get
          {
              return this.CreateQuery<UserEntity>("UserEntities");
          }
      }
```